# SVG : <animate> tag in <refs> to target any svg element

Tags: svg

I'd like to define an `<animate>` tag in my `<defs>` to use it on multiple `<circle>` in my page.

Problems are:

- If I set the `xlink:href` in the animate tag to target one of my circle, and I put a  targeting my animation : the circle is animating; *But I can't reuse my animation on other circles.*
- I can't remove the `xlink:href` from the `<animate>`tag and overide it on the  `<use>`, because the  `<use>` tag already has that attribute (to target the animation).
- Finally if I put the `<use>` of my animation as a child of a `<circle>` tag, the animation doesn't work.

So my question : is there a way to reuse  `<animation>` tags on various SVG elements ?

EDIT : 
I want to define some parameters of my animation in the `<use>`. 
For exemple : `<use xlink:href="myAnim" cx="50" />` or  `<use xlink:href="myAnim" to="50" />`

Comment: By putting the circle in a `<symbol>` you don't need to change the `cx`. You can use a `x` attribute for the `<use>` element as I do in my answer.  Alternatively you may translate the `<use>`.

Comment: @enxaneta You are right : with the `x` attribute I can define the starting point of my circle animation, but not any other animation attribute (`to`, `dur`, etc)

Comment: If you need a different `to` or `dur` you need a different animation. Don't you?

Comment: @enxaneta I'd like to define the basic animation in the `<defs>` : `dur`, `spline`, `fill`, then define one or two specific attribute (typicaly to `to`) on the `<use>`.

Comment: But I guess I just can't

Comment: I understand that you need to change the animation . . . to a different one

Answer (score 0):

If you intend to use the same animation on several circles why not putting the animated circle in the `<defs>` and use the circle?

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg viewBox = "0 0 100 100" width="200">
  <symbol viewBox="0 0 10 100" id="c">
  
  <circle r="5" cy="35" cx="5" >
       <animate 
       attributeName="cy"
       attributeType="XML"
       values="35;95;35"
       dur="5s"
       repeatCount="indefinite"/>
  </circle>
  </symbol>
  
  <use xlink:href="#c" fill="red" width="10" />
  <use xlink:href="#c" fill="gold" width="5"  x="20" />
  <use xlink:href="#c" fill="skyblue" width="7"  x="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Interesting but I wanted to be able to overide some animate attribute on each "use" (different cx typicaly). 
I'll add some precision in my post

Comment: @Neekobus in that case <use> is not suitable. Just clone a template and adjust as necessary.

Comment: @RobertLongson clone a template ?

Comment: Yes ok JS based